# Troubleshooting ionic 4 angular router navigation

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4, angular7-router

so we're attempting to move our project from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4. To begin we started a basic tabs app: ionic start myApp tabs

I made two pages:

```
ionic generate page userList

ionic generate page userDetailed
```

I want two different tabs to have the ability to navigate to "UserListPage". 
So I added it to the "tab1" & "tab2" router children:

**tabs.router.module.ts**

```
{
   path: 'tab1',
   children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          },
          {
             path: 'user-list', 
             loadChildren: './user-list/user-list.module#UserListPageModule' 
          }
        ]
      }
```

Now I want the UserListPage to be able to navigate to the "UserDetailedPage".

I tried adding user-detailed as a path onto the UserListPageModule like so:

**user-list.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserListPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user-detailed',
        loadChildren: '../user-detailed/user-detailed.module#UserDetailedPageModule' 
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now when I'm on tab1 & click a button to go to the list page, it works.

However when I click a button to go from list page to the detailed page, it changes the URL but does not display the page.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your detailed page will be "user-list/user-detailed", your subroutes like user-detailed will be appended to the current route of user-list.

Comment: Right, the URL ends up being "/tabs/tab1/user-list/user-detailed" on the browser but the user-detailed page doesn't show up. It stays on the User List page..

Comment: Into the "user-detailed.ts" have you the template file associated in the annotations?

Comment: yes... I'm starting to wonder if I'm just thinking about routes in the wrong way? Is this the way it's suppose to work?